# How to display entire text record in a HTML table using php 5.5?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I try to display text records from a MySQL table in view of editing and updating them. The problem is that text is not entirely fetched, but only the first word (before the first space in the text). For example for the author 'John Doe' is displayed 'John' and for the book 'Programming in Java', it is displayed only the word 'Programming'. I'm missing something in the code, and I don't know what:

```
 session_start();
 $user = $_SESSION['username'];
 $pass = $_SESSION['password'];
 if(isset($_POST ['Button1']))
 { $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE idUser = '$user'";
  $p = mysql_query($sql, $link);
   echo "<table border=1>
  <tr>
  <th>Author</th>
  <th>Book Title</th>
  </tr>"
  while($record=mysql_fetch_array($p)){
  echo "<form action=edit.php method=post>";
  echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>". "<input type=text name=author value=" .$record['author']. " size=40 ></td>";
  echo "<td>". "<input type=text name=title value=" .$record['bookTitle']. " size=40 ></td>";
 echo "</form>";}
 echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: what happens if you run the SQL directly, using phpmyadmin or MySQL workbench? are you sure the records you are grabbing are what you think they are? also, mysql* functions are deprecated, you should use mysqli or PDO...

Comment: Yes, the database is designed by me, and yes it works with double quotes too. Could be the mysql* functions?

Comment: its an html issue, you need to quote value or you will only see the content up to the space, in your case the first word

Comment: PHP 5.5? You sure that `mysql_` is running on that version? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Might get a deprecation notice.

Comment: It's also best quoting these `<form action=edit.php method=post>` - `<form action='edit.php' method='post'>` and for the others. Some browsers don't like it when unquoted.

Comment: Your HTML is messed up. You do not have any quotes for type, name, and size properties

Comment: Yes @Amir you are right! I am messed up! Fortunately, the answer of Dagon was the good one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your value is missing quotes:

```
 echo '<td><input type=text name=author value="'.$record['author'].'" size=40 ></td>';
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/D7Eh4j

Comment: one problem at a time @Fred-ii-

Comment: Now we did it. OP's disappeared. Or is that "I" did it? ;-)

Comment: you broke the interweb @Fred-ii- (again)

Comment: You were right, Dagon! It was an HTML issue, indeed your answer is correct and helped me a lot! Thank you very much! I want to vote but I can't for the moment, since I have no enough points for reputation. Thank you Fred-ii for your comment, I will use mysqli*. I'm looking now how to put the text on two rows in the HTML table...